# How to positioning MUI Tooltip at the value mark of the progress bar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am creating a progress bar component using the MUI as a foundation. I have tried positioning the Tooltip at the value mark of the progress bar. However, it doesn't seem to work it always appears in the middle. Is there any way to display the Tooltip dynamically based on the progress bar's value?

Plus, this is what it should look like, but I can only achieve having a tooltip in the middle. [image]

this is how much I am able to achieve.[image]

These are the code that I have so far. I did a lot of research, but nobody combined Mui Tooltip and Progress bar. So, I am struggling rn.

```
import { ReactNode, useEffect useState } from 'react'
import MuiLinearProgress, { LinearProgressProps } from '@mui/material/LinearProgress'
import { Box, Tooltip, Typography } from '@mui/material'

type OmitLinear = Omit<LinearProgressProps, 'variant' | 'color'>

interface LinearProps extends OmitLinear {
  variant?: 'circular' | 'linear' | undefined
  color?: string | undefined
  label?: 'end' | 'under' | 'tooltip' | 'arrowTooltip' | undefined
}

type Props = LinearProps

export const Progress = (props: Props) => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
  const {
   variant = 'linear',
   value = progress,
   color,
   size,
   caption,
   captionColor,
   label
  } = props
  const { classes } = useStyles({ color, size, captionColor, label })

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
    setProgress((prevProgress) =>
      (prevProgress >= 100 ?
        0
        :
        prevProgress + 1)
      )
    }, 800)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
      {(variant === 'circular') ?
        (
          // MuiCircular Progress, this one doesn't need Tooltip
        )
        :
        (
          <Box className={classes.boxLinear}>
            <Box className={classes.boxMuiLinear}>
              {(label === 'tooltip' || label === 'arrowTooltip') ? (
                <Tooltip
                  title={`${Math.round(value)}%`}
                  open={true}
                  placement="top"
                  arrow={(label === 'arrowTooltip') ? true : false}
                >
                  <MuiLinearProgress
                    {...props}
                    variant='determinate'
                    color={undefined}
                    value={value}
                    className={classes.rootLinearProgress}
                  />
                </Tooltip>
              ) : (
                <MuiLinearProgress
                  {...props}
                  variant='determinate'
                  color={undefined}
                  value={value}
                  className={classes.rootLinearProgress}
                />
              )}
            </Box>
            {(label === 'end' || label === 'under') ? (
              <Box className={classes.labelBox}>
                <Typography
                  variant="body2"
                  color="text.secondary">
                  {`${Math.round(value)}%`}
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            )
              : null}
          </Box>
        )
      }
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gigi did you find any solution for this? Thanks